# Install php extensions on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, php

I want to install the latest versions of curl, php5-xmlrpc and php5-intl extensions for php 5.4. I have the latest version of php 5.4 (installed via ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable) so the default precise packages for the said extensions will not work. I know this because I tried that first and also tried packages for later versions such as 12.10 and 13.04.

Question is how do I install the latest versions of this extensions and where do I get them from. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

php5-xmlrpc is bundled into PHP as of 4.1.0: http://php.net/manual/en/xmlrpc.installation.php

php5-intl is too as of PHP 5.3.0: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

For curl, you'll need to install a few more libraries to get it to work:

```
 sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

Comment: thanks, but as I already said, the defaults in repos do not work since I have the latest version of php (5.4). That would work fine for someone with php 5.3 but not in my case :(